# Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser does not load local file, if there are get parameters

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am trying to load local html file like this

```
    WebBrouser = new WebBrowser();
    WebBrouser.Navigate(new Uri("index.html?param1=foo&param2=bar", UriKind.Relative);
```

It says it can not find the page. If I remove the parameters, it works. 
How can I pass get parameters to local html file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use # instead of ?

example:

```
browser.Navigate(new Uri("www/index.html#p=123&p2=567", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Yes, this was one solution. I came to another - call javascript function directly from c#. Thank you anyway.